# Dynamic class loading with Java

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic

I want to dynamically load a concrete class which implements an interface. Input: concrete class name.

I need to call a method in this concrete class, that is, I'll need to set:

```
MyInterface myclass = new concreteClassName();
myclass.function();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: note that `class` is a java key-word, and you cannot name your variable class

Comment: What you mean by dynamic loading?

Comment: @amil : i edited it now , it was just an example

Comment: @umbr : to dynamically load a class , means to load it at run time with a class identifier , instead of instaniating the normal constructors , it is useful in many cases

Answer (score 6):

have a look at [Class.forName(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

```
    String str = "Test$B"; //your full class name here instead of Test$B
    A clazz = null; //change A to be your interface
    try { 
    clazz = (A)Class.forName(str).newInstance(); //change A to be your interface

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        //TODO: handle exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (clazz != null)  {
        clazz.foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out

```
try {
     // Load class
     Class<?> cls = Class.forName("my.package.ConcreteClass");

     // Instantiate object from class using default constructor
     my.package.ConcreteClass obj = (my.package.ConcreteClass) cls.newInstance(); 

     // Execute method on it
     obj.myMethod(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not instantiate class", e);
}
```

and the respective javadoc entries for `Class#forName` and `Class#newInstance`?

Comment: but i want to call my class through the interface not directly call my.package.ConcreteClass

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own [ClassLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Comment: that will be my last option , but i think there is a more easier solution

Comment: feasibly you may find (by Google :) already existing libs with that functionality