# How to get a SubClass Instance, when i know the Class name as String in java?

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

I want to create instances of java classes (which all extend a superclass) at runtime.

Here some Example classes:

```
class Super {
}

class FirstSub extends Super {
}

class SecondSub extends Super {
}
```

I know the class name as string:

```
String name = "SubClassName";
```

This was my first approach:

```
Super foo;
if (FirstSub.class.getSimplename().equals(name)) {
    foo = new FirstSub();
}
if (SecondSub.class.getSimplename().equals(name)) {
    foo = new SecondSub();
}
```

How do i get an instance of one of the "subclasses" in a more sophisticated way?

EDIT: Additionally I want to cast `foo` to `SubClassName`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Class loading with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220601/dynamic-class-loading-with-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Class myClass = Class.forName(name);
Object o = myClass.newInstance();
Super instance = (Super)o;
//Subclass instance2 = (Subclass)o;
```

Dynamically casting that your variable reference will be Subclass is impossible and non-worthy. If in this place your object could be FirstSub or SecondSub then both of this object should provide some given functionality (method). You should define some (e.g. abstract) method in superclass (or make it interface). Then, if you have such line:

```
Super instance = (Super)o;
```

where o is instance of subclass of Super, then invoking your method would invoke method on subclass. This is beauty of polymorphism

Comment: `Class class`? `class` is a protected key word in java, this code will not compile

Comment: +1: Note: newInstance() will throw a checked exception as if there were unchecked exception which surprising behaviour. You should place a try/catch(Exception) block around it.

Comment: How would i cast the instance to `SubClassName`? With this code, the type is always `Super`

Comment: this is actually polymorphism. You should have overriden methods in subclasses and interface (or just other method) in superclass. After you create concrete instance of subclass you can invoke method which signature lies in superclass and then the subclasses method would  be invoked

Comment: @Martin, the last line in Matthew's example is a cast to the super class.

Answer (score 3):

```
Super s = (Super) Class.forName(str).newInstance();
```

i guess this will work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example

```
try{
   Class my_class = Class.forName(class_name);
   // use my_class object to
   Object initClassObj = my_class.newInstance();
}catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
   // handle exception
}catch(Exception ex){
   // handle other exception 
}
```

Comment: ;) this is correct for the title (an instance of `Class` for a known class name), but it looks like, the question is about instantiating